# htaccess how to set something like catch all links to one index.html?

Tags: .htaccess, catch-all

I have to disable CMS and there are a lot of link in the air, ight now there is only static page on html5 
how to set something like catch all addresses from domain and redirect them to main index.html

I try to add

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

but not working

Comment: Though that rule certainly can be optimized still it _should_ work. Since it does not there has to be something else that is wrong. So: how did you make sure that your rule is interpreted _at all_ ? What happens if you place a definite syntax error in that file? Where is that file located? Is the interpretation of such files enabled at all for that location? How did you make sure your are not looking at cached results?